# How do I exit if a third party command waits for input?

Tags: bash

I have a third party command that I can't modify that I want call and capture the output of, but if the file provided to it is missing some parameters, it prompts for user input. I consider this an error case and want to kill the command and show an error message.

```sh
RESULT=$(third-party-command --parameters=parameters.json)

echo "$RESULT"
```

How can I achieve this? The command runs for an unpredicable amount of time.

Comment: How unpredictable? If you know how long is certainly too long, you could use `timeout`.

Comment: If you haven't already, check that your third party command doesn't provide a "non-interactive" flag you could set to raise an error when the command needs a value it would otherwise prompt for

Comment: @oguzismail I didn't know that was possible, thanks. That causes `third-party-command` to exit with an error, which is fine for this use case. If you want to create an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try closing `third-party-command`'s stdin, so that it will fail to read user input and most probably exit with an error.

```
third-party-command --parameters=parameters.json <&-
```

Comment: Equally running `third-party < /dev/null` has been known to work for some interactive programs - e.g. Solaris `format < /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

As [Benjamin W. noted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57892284/519360#comment102206376_57892284), use [GNU timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html):

```
RESULT="$(timeout --signal=HUP --kill-after=5 2 \
            third-party-command --parameters="parameters.json" <&-)"
```

This will give a [HUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) (hang-up) [signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) to `third-party-command` after two seconds and a [KILL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGKILL) signal after five seconds if it's still running. (See `man 7 signal` for more detail, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15606/87770) for why HUP is ideal for a first pass at killing interactive programs.)

By piping in a closed file descriptor (`<&-` as [suggested by oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57893377/519360)), we've cut off inputs. It's preferable to find a flag for that (as [suggested by Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57892284/519360#comment102206465_57892284)), but you may not have that option. You can also consider piping [`yes`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/yes-invocation.html) into it, which will continuously input `y` or a custom string.